# PHP/MYSQLI insert_id for foreign key value - $id variable set but not working in INSERT query

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, insert-id

Using the code below, I am auto-incrementing an ID value as a primary key in the constant_client table, which then needs to be used as a foreign key in the varying_client table. The first prepared statement works correctly, and the $id variable which is set to $conn->insert_id also appears to work, as when echoing the statement I am getting the correct incremented value from the first table. However, when attempting the second query, I am getting a "Call to a member function bind_param() on bool" error.

```
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO constant_client (on_programme, last_name, first_name, middle_name,
      date_birth, gender, ohs, maiden_name, marital_status, ethnicity, height, weight, hair_colour,
    eye_colour, tattoos, features, chronic, disabilities)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("isssssisssssssssss", $on_programme, $last_name, $first_name, $middle_name, $date_birth,
    $gender, $ohs, $maiden_name, $marital_status, $ethnicity, $height, $weight, $hair_colour,
    $eye_colour, $tattoos, $features, $chronic, $disabilities);
    $stmt->execute();
    $id = $conn->insert_id;

    echo $id;

      $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO varying_client (id, address, suburb, postcode, state, client_phone, client_mobile
      emergency_contact, emergency_phone)
      VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
      $stmt->bind_param('issisiisi', $id, $address, $suburb, $postcode, $state, $client_phone, $client_mobile,
      $emergency_contact, $emergency_phone);
      $stmt->execute();

    $conn->close();
```

I'm very new to prepared statements, so it is entirely possible that I am messing up the syntax somewhere, but if anyone could shed some light on it it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and see what the driver says the error is.

Comment: You're using integer columns for phone numbers?

Comment: @user3783243 there is a better way, see the linked answer. Carbs, just ask your database to tell you what's the problem when something goes wrong.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, all it was was an errant comma, but I just learnt a great lesson in error checking. Much appreciated all.